# Some Elements in Vue components are not showing when called in a Single Vue File

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I've completed designing my components with Vue 2, Vuetify and Vue cli - 4.5.15. I tried combining it in a Single Vue file but the components are not showing <v-icons> <v-textfield> and some other elements. I am not sure about why these kind of errors happen. I've attached the code of Component1 and Component2 and also the App.vue file's code.

Also in Control Panel I'm continuously getting error stating

> Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rtl')"

Component 1

```html
<template>
  <div class="post-wrap">
    <div class="post-header">
        <img src="https://www.finetoshine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Beautiful-Girl-Wallpapers-New-Photos-Images-Pictures.jpg" alt="" class="avator">
        <div class="post-header-info">
            <a class="location-link mintext"><v-icon small>mdi-map-marker</v-icon> BVB School, Thindal</a>
            <span style="float:right;margin-right: 10px;" class="mintext">Jun 21</span>
            <br>
            &nbsp;<div style="margin-top:6px;margin-left:1px;display:inline-block;font-size:16px;">Steve Jobs</div> 
            &nbsp;·<span class="mintext"> Attended a Seminar</span>
            <p> If you're tired of using outline styles for secondary buttons, a soft solid background based on the text color can be a great alternative.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="align-straight">
      <img src="https://www.gizbot.com/images/2020-09/realme-7_159921061900.jpg" class="multi-img">
      <img src="https://www.gizbot.com/images/2020-09/realme-7_159921061900.jpg" class="multi-img">
    </div>
    <span class="attached-link"> + 2 images</span><br>
    <div class="align-straight">
      <div class="document-wrap" style="display: inline-block;">
        <v-icon dense>mdi-file-document</v-icon> document 
      </div>
      <div class="document-wrap" style="display: inline-block;">
        + 2 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="align-straight like-bar">
      <span><v-icon>mdi-thumb-up</v-icon></span>
      <span style="float:right;margin-right: 20px;"><v-icon>mdi-bookmark</v-icon></span>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>
```

Component 2

```html
<template>
<div class="newpost-wrap">
  <v-form>
    <div class="newpost-title">What's up</div>
    <v-select label="Post Type" v-model="selectedPost" :items="postTypes" outlined></v-select>
    <v-textarea v-model="newPost" :counter="280" label="New Post" hint="Share your Achievement !" required outlined></v-textarea>
    <span class="update-link" @click="showAttach=!showAttach"><v-icon color="#3a7bd5">mdi-attachment</v-icon> Attach Files</span>
    <div class="newpost-icons" v-if="showAttach==true">
      <v-file-input  small-chips  multiple dense prepend-icon="mdi-wallpaper" accept="image/*" ></v-file-input>
      <v-file-input  small-chips  multiple dense prepend-icon="mdi-file-document" accept="document/pdf, document/docx"></v-file-input>
    </div>
    <div class="update-btn">Post</div>
  </v-form>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      showAttach: false,
      newPost: '',
      postType: null,
      selectedPost: 'Usual',
      postTypes: ['Seminar', 'Course', 'Project', 'Usual']
    })
  }
</script>
```

App.vue

```html
<template>
  <v-app >
      <NewPostBar />
      <UsualPost />
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import NewPostBar from '/fac/faculty/src/components/NewPostBar.vue'
import UsualPost from '/fac/faculty/src/components/UsualPost.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    NewPostBar,UsualPost
  },
  data: () => ({
  })
};
</script>
```

Comment: Code which installs Vuetify as Vue Plugin:

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib/framework';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
});

Comment: In main.js file...

Code:

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  **vuetify**,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! Just now kind of solved it... What happened was I didn't install router when initializing project, so the error raised...Now I did the initialization of router when creating the project. And now the site is working fine...!  

Thank You So Much @tony19 

Answer (score 1):

**Solved:**

Hope this answers similar problems...

First I initialized a Vue project without including a router but then installed it as a plugin...then I got this error

So I initialized a Fresh project with a router installed with that...Now there's no error in the console, and the Project works just fine

> But I am genuinely not aware of why this happened

Thanks to @tony19 for your response, So I was keep checking what was going wrong...